# awk: if condition is met, add string to these lines

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to combine these two commands:

```
awk -F[' '] '{if ($1=="string" || $4=="string") print $0" ""blue"}' file >file.out 
awk -F[' '] '{if ($1!="string" && $4!="string") print $0}' file >>file.out
```

Basically I want to add a column, but only print `blue` in that column if either the first or the fourth column are equal to a `string`.

input:

```
string 123 452 abc
def 420 902 ghi
```

expected output:

```
string 123 452 abc blue
def 420 902 ghi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a single pass like

```
 awk '$1 == "string" || $4 == "string" {print $0 " blue"; next} {print}' file > file.out
```

which will test if either the first or forth field is `string` and will print the line followed by `blue` if so.  We use `next` then to not process the next block (rather than doing the negated test we just did).  Any line we didn't print with `blue` on, we just print as it was.

Answer (score 4):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '$1=="string" || $4=="string"{ NF+=1; $NF="blue" }1' file
string 123 452 abc blue
def 420 902 ghi
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 awk '{print $0 (($1 == "string" || $4 == "string") ? OFS "blue":"")}' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

Another similar alternative:

```
awk '$1=="string" || $4=="string" {$0=$0" blue"} 1' infile
```

Output:

```
string 123 452 abc blue
def 420 902 ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

Following may also help you, where I am not mentioning the field numbers in check condition(considering that your Input_file is same as shown sample), so it looks if a line starts from string "string" and ends from string "string" then it prints blue else print normal line.

```
awk '/^string/||/string$/{print $0,"blue";next} 1'  Input_file
```